# Get plain value from custom variable in php with objectManager

Tags: magento2, php, object-manager, custom-variable

I want to get a plain value from custom variable (defined on admin) in php with objectManager.

`storeID is in $order->getStore()->getId()`

`Custom Variable Code is 'mycustomvar'`

why does following code not work?

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $variables = $objectManager->create('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable');
    if ($var = $variables->getResource()->getVariableByCode('mycustomvar', true, $order->getStore()->getId())) {
        $value = 'defined';
//      $value = $variables->getData('plain_value');
    } else {
        $value = 'undefined';
    }
```

It looks like `$var` contains the array with the values of mycustomvar, but I'm not sure.

How can I pass `$var` to `getData('plain_value')`?  Or is there a better way to get `'plain_value'`?

Classes I was looking into are

`Magento\Variable\Model\Variable`

`Magento\Variable\Model\ResourceModel\Variable`

PS I understood objectManager is not the preferred way, but I need to get this working here

PPS Magento 2.1

Comment: You can use $model = $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('myVariable');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
$html_value = $model->getHtmlValue();

But this method is not recommend by Magento to create instance.

Comment: @Vikas Sorry, I don't understand - how would I set the storeID then?

Comment: This will automatically provide you the current store value. Did you use it ?

Comment: No - I need to get different values of this custom variable depending on which store the document was created.This is part of a modificaton of function insertOrder in Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstractpdf.php and I checked the storeId is in $order->getStore()->getId(), for example storeId = 3.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Magento\Variable\Model\Variable` offers everything - such as setStoreId(StoreId), which needs to be set case by case for my application. There is no need to dig into `Magento\Variable\Model\ResourceModel\Variable`.

The following code is working now. Replace `myStoreID` and `mycustomvar` with your needs. Remove code line with setStoreId(StoreId), if you need access to `mycustomvar` in the current store.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $variables = $objectManager->create('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable');
    $variables->setStoreId(myStoreID);

    $value = $variables->loadByCode('mycustomvar')->getPlainValue();
```

Thanks to Vikas comments, it helped me find the solution.